# Value of type 'NSFetchRequest' has no member 'performFetch'

Tags: swift

I write code

```
    var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Doctor")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id != nil")



let sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor] = [(NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "distance", ascending: true)), (NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "lastname", ascending: true))]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

var error: NSError? = nil
```

// show error  Value of type 'NSFetchRequest' has no member 'performFetch'

```
var fetchSuccessful: Bool = fetchRequest.performFetch(error)
```

Comment: NSFetchRequest indeed does not have such a method

Comment: Core Data is tricky at first to understand and use. Best to get hold of a template that works and stick to that until you get more comfortable with how and why it is structured the way it is. All the best!!

Answer (score 1):

@Magdalena Dziesińska: In your code...

```
var fetchSuccessful: Bool = fetchRequest.performFetch(error)
```

"performFetch" does not exist. To handle the error (error handling) place it within a 'do-try-catch statement' e.g. after your code...

```
 var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Doctor")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id != nil")
```

let sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor] = [(NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "distance", ascending: true)), (NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "lastname", ascending: true))]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

Use the following do-try-catch statement to catch any errors and get the fetch request.

```
do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    } catch {
        print("requesting error")
    }
```

nb: request is where you place your "fetchRequest"

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform fetch request without context. If you have `NSManagedObjectContext` instance, you may use it `executeFetchRequest(_:)` method with your fetch request. More, if you have `NSFetchedResultsController` instance, initialized by your fetch request, you can use `performFetch()` method of this controller. You absolutely need to read more documentation of CoreData https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`executeFetchRequest(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/executeFetchRequest:error:) which `throws` rather than using taking an `NSError` param.

> If the last non-block parameter of an Objective-C method is of type NSError **, Swift replaces it with the throws keyword, to indicate that the method can throw an error. If the Objective-C method’s error parameter is also its first parameter, Swift attempts to simplify the method name further, by removing the “WithError” or “AndReturnError” suffix, if present, from the first part of the selector. If another method is declared with the resulting selector, the method name is not changed. - [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.2) - Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10)